# Why do .gitignore files for Unity omit .unitypackage files?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

I'm using Git to share files for student demos and realized `.unitypackage` files are automatically ignored by `.gitignore` files. For example, the [gitignore.io version](https://www.gitignore.io/api/unity,macos,windows). Why is this? What am I risking if I remove this?

Comment: because normally those are not inside your unity project, but loaded into it

Comment: It's a bad idea to check in dependencies or build artifacts into your repository.

Comment: I want to add samples for them to work on *and* include projects. Since this is not one project but a lot of samples then perhaps I can ignore convention?  https://github.com/omundy/game-art-dev